# Xampp not working on m1 Mac book pro giving me a error :

Tags: macos, xampp, backend, web-development-server, apple-m1

I am new to Osx operating system, I have bought an m1 mac book pro and install xampp on it but it always gives me an error (an error will be listed below), can you guys pls help my feel free to hit me up on discord on email

**error I am getting:**

INFO: Starting "XAMPP" stack
ERROR: Error starting "XAMPP" stack: cannot calculate MAC address: hv_vm_create unknown error -85377023

Comment: cannot calculate MAC address: Using fd 13 for I/O notifications
hv_vm_create unknown error 0x00000004 Mac m1 not working, and showing it error.
please share with us your feedback and fix it this problem thanks HS hardeepguleria007@gmail.com

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Proceed to https://www.apachefriends.org/de/download.html and look for OSX Downloads. There are 6 different Download Links, choose any of the three UPPER links (Size 163mb or 164mb). DO NOT Download one of the LOWER three (Size 358mb).

If you have Big Sur then check this:
[https://www.robotem.net/xampp-not-working/#:~:text=Xampp%20not%20working%20Solved%2C%20some,XAMPP%207.4.&text=Although%20the%20problem%20seems%20to,the%20problem%20is%20getting%20worse](https://www.robotem.net/xampp-not-working/#:%7E:text=Xampp%20not%20working%20Solved%2C%20some,XAMPP%207.4.&text=Although%20the%20problem%20seems%20to,the%20problem%20is%20getting%20worse).

Comment: Thanks. Using `*-installer.dmg` solve this problem

Comment: What about macOS Moneterey?

Comment: @prk_passion01 check this article it might be helpful https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-monterey-apache-multiple-php-versions